# How to call main activity from the navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created an navigation drawer which has an home option which i want to redirect it to the main activity.
All the rest options open up an fragment.

I am getting an error saying getactivity is not defined. 
Is it possible to call the activity from the activity itself.
If yes, can i get the code.

I have removed some part of the code as it is default while creating navigation drawer.
Here is my main activity:

```
private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            Intent in = new Intent(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        case R.id.nav_contact_us:
            fragment = new ContactUs();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_how_to_convert:
            fragment = new HowAppWorks();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_team:
            fragment = new Team();
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Keep this instead of this.getActivity()

Comment: Are you currently in fragment or Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NB: The Activity class doesn't have a getActivity() method

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

As You said you are in MainActivity and still you want to move in MainActivity infect it is bad Approach, you can just refresh data or reload views only.. But if still want that here is the problem in your code as assuming its MainActivity Code use MainActivity.this in context not this. getActivity();

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```